# How to create new External Content Type on SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, external-content-type

I'm trying to create a new External Content Type on Sharepint Designer , but where I try to insert the web services wisdom into the "New Connection -> WCF Connection "  I get the following error:

> "***The URL should not Loop back to the local host"***

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/690b71c4-77d1-45c5-bf9a-88848d7c09ba/) on MSDN you should:

> Change 'localhost' to  in your target url.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira - so did it solved your problem?

Comment: OK, I have changed the application configuration on IIS. The address of this local application is now : My network adapter IP and my PC Name. But now I get the error: "specify a valid and point URL" –

Comment: How did you connect to your WCF Service usually, using FQDN or COMPUTENAME:PORT - use that! (do you launch your WCF from VS2010 by any chance in a CASINI WEb Server?)